# Cannot configure timeout from connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection, connection-timeout

I have created this stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test AS
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DEALY '00:00:40'
END
```

I have also written a C# console app to test the connect timeout property.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    OpenSqlConnection();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void OpenSqlConnection()
{
    string connectionString = GetConnectionString();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.test", connection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
        {
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("ConnectionTimeout: {0}", connection.ConnectionTimeout);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}

static private string GetConnectionString()
{
    return
            "Data Source=test.com;Initial Catalog=test_db;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=10; Application Name=Test";
}
```

There was a connection timeout exception returned as excepted (timeout in connection string < 40s). However, when I changed the Connect Timeout property to 120, I still got the same timeout exception. After some trial and error, it seems that the timeout value is always 30s regardless of my connection string value.

Is the connection timeout controlled by somewhere else? (if yes, where?)

Why the connect timeout value in connection string has no effect on my console app?

**Update**

Thanks all. I have just noticed that the command timeout is different from connection timeout(timeout in connection string).

Instead of changing my `app.config`, I would have to specify the `CommandTimeout` property as Sudipta Maiti suggested and recompile my code.

There is a similar issue in:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1197160.aspx?Can+you+change+command+timeout+via+the+connection+string+

Comment: The **connect timeout** handles how long the code will wait for a **connection** to be made - ***NOT*** for how long a query runs *after* the connection already has been made! That would be a **command timeout**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CommandTimeout:

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.test", connection) {    
CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
{
      connection.Open();
      Console.WriteLine("ConnectionTimeout: {0}", 
      connection.ConnectionTimeout);
      command.CommandTimeout = 120;
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      Console.WriteLine("Finished");
      connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect the given ***Timeout***, it may not be enough to complete your operations. So make it `Connection Timeout=30;`

`Connect Timeout -or- Connection Timeout` by `default` the value will be `15` seconds. Based on your operation performance you might need to extend the seconds.

When a connection is returned to the pool, its creation time is compared with the current time, and the connection is destroyed if that time span (in seconds) exceeds the value specified by [Connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.90).aspx) Lifetime. This is useful in clustered configurations to force load balancing between a running server and a server just brought online.

A value of zero (0) causes pooled connections to have the maximum connection timeout.

[There is a Sample Source almost same as yours.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout(v=vs.90).aspx)